# Disable “snap” sound when taking pictures?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

Is it possible to completely disable the “snap” sound when taking pictures with an iPhone?

I find this sound very irritating.

Comment: You can mute the phone while taking pictures.

Comment: Unless you're in one of the jurisdictions that don't allow it, like Japan.